# SQL: Invalid column names

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, import-table

I am trying to upload a table, and it is giving me the error message: "The following new table has invalid names: ". It did not point out which one is invalid. All my column names are words. Not sure what rules can I possibly violate. Below is a screenshot.

[image]

`DMS    NOTDMS  engine  arsenic sediment    cartilage   articular   bone    freight solutions   neutrino    heart   stripe  plasma  indoor  calcium power   fixture     eye chloride    tellurium   alloys  egg corrosion   market  antenna     metal   ice quantum  invasibility   interrupt   ventilation ammonia     pollen  syringae    text    auxin   editing compression copper  dpp clock   enduring    taxes   blue    kinase  dolomite    meristem    isoprene    proteins    halo    context information type    detector    oxygen  invariants  aequorin    attractors  ribosome    actin   cellulose   tubulin binding site    disulfide   midgut  alternative oxidase fischeri    agreement   snow    cements   excluded  attitudes   law nucleotide  music   homotopy    periplasmic translocation   stomatal    phosphoprotein  flagellar   late    motors  operons replication sigma   recombination   streamflow  fluidity    police  muscle  blood   heme    replicative kelps   estrogen    elderly witnesses   fire    splicing    scaffolding subunits    erosion reef    climate abnormal    operator    holographic braided seeding kidney  cortical    photonic     functor       homology river   alluvial    sand    inlet   import  nitrogenase aleurone    maturation  guard   light   inositol    membrane    clay    lightning   recycling   amoebae dyneins thioredoxin coat    3-manifolds mercury diving  sludge  sources fluorine    conductivity    hydraulic   glucose designs condensate  amorphous   treeline`

Comment: paste your column names..may be one of them is keyword or contaisn invalid character

Comment: Column 'engine' might be causing the problem.

Comment: The list is really long...

Comment: Please check there is no space between column name like ` fixture eye chloride` if it is one column then it is the cause

Comment: They are separate columns.

Comment: You might be using keyword as column name.

Comment: Do you know which one is keyword? I listed them all above. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short version:

- column names are not the problem
- title of error messages may indicate that not every record has the datatype you want them to be

I imported a flat-file (csv) with the same column-names you provided above using microsoft sql server 2008 R2 Express. The import worked fine; every column names was imported. Could it be that your column names have some non-visible characters that are causing the trouble?

If you provide more information we can help better.

- which version of sql server are you using
- provide the source of your file
- provide additional error information and the way you are importing the file

My answer is that the column names are not the problem - at least not with sql server 2008 R2 express.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle keywords:

- **type** (in *information type*)

SQL keywords may caused the issue:

- **power**
- **operator**

You need to change those column names to avoid any further error.

How to check: Paste the list into any SQL editor (Notepad++). The keywords are highlighted.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar problem (Using Oracle SQL Developer 3.2)

My issue was that I have an index column (with no name). Thus it couldnt be selected, and it displayed as nothing on the error prompt.

Hopefully this helps anyone who might be facing the same issue